# Reverse engineer the schema to make an extended ER diagram

Tags: entity-relationship, reverse-engineering

would anyone have suggestions as to which is the sub classes and which one is the superclass, or how I would reverse engineer it to make an extended ER diagram?

```
r1{A,B,C,D}  Key is A
r2{A,X,K}    Key is A,X
r3{S,T}      Key is S
r4{A,S,V}    Key is V
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one possible E-R to DDL mapping: inheritance could be flattened upwards or downwards or splitted, n-to-n relationships spawn a bridge table, etc.

Therefore, the only way to reconstruct E-R from DDL is reverse engineering. You will have to figure out the meaning of given entities (`r1`...) and fields (`A`...) and then speculate on which relationships might have been established between each pair of entities.

The reconstructed E-R might still differ from the original one, based on which choices were taken by the original architect. Some relationships might even have been omitted.